# Showing all records on a webpage

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, sql-injection

I have a connection with my database to show all my records on a webpage, and I'm not sure if this code is safe:

```
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', null);
define('DB_DATABASE', 'publicacoes');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'bn');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

function DBEscape($dados){
    $link = DBConnect();

    if(!is_array($dados))
        $dados = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $dados);
    else{
        $arr = $dados;

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $key = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $key);
            $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value);

            $dados[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    DBclose($link);
    return $dados;
}

function DBclose($link){
    @mysqli_close($link) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}

function DBConnect(){
    $link = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARSET) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    return $link;
}

function DBRead($table, $params = null, $fields = '*'){
    $table  = DB_PREFIX.'_'.$table;
    $params = ($params) ? " {$params}" : null;

    $query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
    $result = DBExecute($query);

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
        return false;
    else{
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[] = $res;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

function DBExecute($query, $insertId = false){
    $link   = DBConnect();
    $result = @mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    if($insertId)
        $result = mysqli_insert_id($link);


    DBClose($link);
    return $result;
}

$dadosIDrow1 = DBRead('publicacao', "ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2");

<?php foreach ($dadosUN as $UN): ?>

//some html here to display the records

<?php endforeach; ?
```

This is the first piece of code that I've written to show the records on my website. At the moment I have 2 connections with my DB. One of them I use PDO prepared statement to a pagination and search box.

I want to know if I should delete this script and make a new one with prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if I should delete this script and make a new one with prepared statements.

Yes, definitely.
This set of functions is just unacceptable, being so bad on so many levels.

- There will be *dozens to hundreds* connections made in your script, not just "2 connections" for starter, as your code will connect anew every time it executes a query.
- There is, as you rightfully noted, no support for prepared statements, which is a disaster alone. That escaping routine is based on the false notion that mysqli_real_escape_string's purpose is to protect you from SQL injection. Well, it's but a [grave delusion](https://phpdelusions.net/top#escaping).
- [error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) is completely flawed. What a *site user* is supposed to do with a blank page telling them that a column not found?
- a `DBRead()` function is silly. All its purpose is to save you a typing of two words. *Seriously?* And this trifle gain at the expense of making a gibberish out of the powerful language of SQL.

To show 2 records from a table (as it's stated in the code as opposed to the question title) you need only two lines with vanilla PDO, so you better stick with it:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM publicacao ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2';
$dadosUN = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();
?>
<?php foreach ($dadosUN as $UN): ?>

//some html here to display the records

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! But, what is the purpose of using `$pdo->query` istead of `prepare?`, i was thinking more about this: $stmtIDrow1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM bn_publicacao ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2");
$stmtIDrow1->execute();

Comment: You don't have to prepare queries that do not accept data variables.